# An inequality involving the AM-GM inequality: $| x + \frac1x | \ge 2 $ (for $x<0$).

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Suppose $x \neq 0 $, then $| x + \frac{1}{x} | \geq 2 $.

I have shown this using the am gm inequality $(a+b)/2 \geq \sqrt{ab} $. In fact, with $a = x^2 $ and $b=1$ works. So, for $x > 0 $ we have proved the ineqality above. How can we handle the case $x < 0$ ?

Comment: Have you checked on Math. SE ?  Very similar questions have been answered before

Comment: $|x+\frac1x|=|-x+\frac 1{-x}|$

Comment: ataulfo, what u wrote doesnt make sense.

Comment: Why not? That a hint to handle the case $x<0$ (then $-x>0$.

Comment: Some related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439671, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705064 and many other questions which you can find [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/705064). Although it seems that you are mainly asking what to do for $x>0$, which makes your question a bit different from the ones I linked.

Comment: @Ataulfo Since the main problem of the OP seems to be how to get from $x>0$ to the case $x<0$, perhaps you could expand your comment a bit and post it as an answer.

Comment: @user135395 You wrote that you used AM-GM for the case $x>0$. I just want to point out that you would get the same result a bit faster using it with $a=x$ and $b=\frac1x$.

Answer (score 5):

You can prove the result at once by writing

$$\left(x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + 2 \ge 2\sqrt{x^2\cdot \frac{1}{x^2}} + 2 = 4,$$

then taking square roots.

Comment: Or $=\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+4\ge 4$.